# RESTORE HEADERONLY Error 3013 after the sp1 was applied to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have recently applied SP1 to SQL Server 2014, done and dusted, no issue.
Few weeks later, when trying to use one of my Stored Procedures to restore one of the databases from a bak file from the network, the following error message was thrown:

> Error RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally. Error 3013.

Within the stored procedure, I have the following two lines of code to get the database name from the bak file.

```
SET @strCheck = N'RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK ='''+@backupFile+'''';

INSERT INTO #headerOnly EXEC(@strCheck);
```

After a long day spent scratching my head, I have realized that SQL Server 2014 sp1 has added 3 new columns to the output of Restore HeaderOnly. The temp table in the code was created on a previous version of SQL Server, SQL Server 2014 and didn't have the last three columns therefore, the insert failed with the error 3013.

The new columns in SQL Server 2014 sp1 are the following 3:

```
KeyAlgorithm nvarchar(32); 
EncryptorThumbprint varbinary(20); 
EncryptorType nvarchar(32);
```

Answer (score 1):

We have a Windows C/S application, where databases can be exported, imported and copied. To test SQL Server 2014, we had imported some dabases from a SQL Server 2008 and done some (successful) tests with 2014 some times ago.
Now we have installed SP1 and then also had problems with other error-messages (like e.g. "Cannot open backup device").
I then also have lost a full day until I found the information, that SP1 add's three new columns (unfortunately before I have found this posting).

So.. I had to add the three new fields in the SP to the definition of the restoreheader:

```
CREATE TABLE #restoreheader(
BackupName nvarchar(128)
, BackupDescription nvarchar(255)
, BackupType smallint
, ExpirationDate datetime
, Compressed tinyint
, Position smallint
, DeviceType tinyint
, UserName nvarchar(128)
, ServerName nvarchar(128)
, DatabaseName nvarchar(128)
, DatabaseVersion int
, DatabaseCreationDate datetime
, BackupSize numeric(20,0)
, FirstLSN numeric(25,0)
, LastLSN numeric(25,0)
, CheckpointLSN numeric(25,0)
, DatabaseBackupLSN numeric(25,0)
, BackupStartDate datetime
, BackupFinishDate datetime
, SortOrder smallint
, [CodePage] smallint
, UnicodeLocaleId int
, UnicodeComparisonStyle int
, CompatibilityLevel tinyint
, SoftwareVendorId int
, SoftwareVersionMajor int
, SoftwareVersionMinor int
, SoftwareVersionBuild int
, MachineName nvarchar(128)
, Flags int
, BindingID uniqueidentifier
, RecoveryForkID uniqueidentifier
, Collation nvarchar(128)
, FamilyGUID uniqueidentifier
, HasBulkLoggedData bit
, IsSnapshot bit
, IsReadOnly bit
, IsSingleUser bit
, HasBackupChecksums bit
, IsDamaged bit
, BeginsLogChain bit
, HasIncompleteMetaData bit
, IsForceOffline bit
, IsCopyOnly bit
, FirstRecoveryForkID uniqueidentifier
, ForkPointLSN numeric(25,0) NULL
, RecoveryModel nvarchar(60)
, DifferentialBaseLSN numeric(25,0) NULL
, DifferentialBaseGUID uniqueidentifier
, BackupTypeDescription nvarchar(60)
, BackupSetGUID uniqueidentifier NULL
, CompressedBackupSize bigint NULL
, containment tinyint not NULL
, KeyAlgorithm nvarchar(32)
, EncryptorThumbprint varbinary(20)
, EncryptorType nvarchar(32)
)
```

Notes:
See the **last four** fields in the definition.
The Field **containment tinyint not NULL** was added in SQL-Server **2012** so.. you also have to add this field (if not already added).
I simply have added the new fields at the end of the definition.. and now everything works like before (no further changes).

So.. this is a **breaking change** to SQL-Server 2014 **SP1**, as soon, as you use a restoreheader definition in your SP's.
I don't have found any information to that (**has to be changed**) in the official MS release notes.
Only information I found, see below...

**MS text to "SQL Server 2014 Service Pack 1 release Information":**

> 1957464 RESTORE HEADERONLY for an Encrypted Backup file of the
>   Database does not show whether the backup is encrypted or not. After
>   you apply SP1, the output of RESTORE HEADONLY will include three
>   additional columns: KeyAlgorithm, EncryptorThumbprint and
>   EncryptorType that can give additional details about the encrypted
>   backup.